How to isolate the clickable area for a responsive mobile menu using React and TailwindCSS
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { RxHamburgerMenu } from "react-icons/rx";
import { FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";
import Logo from '../assets/Logo.svg';

function Navbar() {
  //  nav is starting off false
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false)
  // so when user clicks Hamburger buttom, it gomes from false(!nav) to true(nav)
  const handleClick = () => setNav(!nav)

  return (
    <header data-aos="fade" data-aos-duration="300" className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 relative shadow-lg " >
    <nav>
      <div className="max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4">
        <NavLink to="/" className="flex items-center space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse"><img src={Logo} alt="" width="200" className='h-15'/></NavLink>
        <div className="flex md:order-2 space-x-3 md:space-x-0 rtl:space-x-reverse relative">
          <NavLink to="/contact/"><button type="button" className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Contact Us</button></NavLink>
       
              {/* Hamburger or Close Icon */}
          </div>
          <div className='md:hidden z-10' onClick={handleClick}>
            { nav ? <FaTimes size={25} color='white'/> : <RxHamburgerMenu size ={25}/>}
            <ul className={`${
              nav 
              ? 'text-white opacity-100 transform translate-x-0'
              : 'opacity-0 transform -translate-y-full'} transition-transform absolute top-20 w-full h-screen left-0 bg-zinc-800/80 flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-2xl
              `}>
              <NavLink to='/'><li className='p-2 hover:text-blue-500'>Home</li></NavLink>
              <NavLink to='/services'><li className='p-2 hover:text-blue-500'>Services</li></NavLink>
              <NavLink to='/solutions'><li className='p-2 hover:text-blue-500'>Solutions</li></NavLink>
              <NavLink to='/about'><li className='p-2 hover:text-blue-500'>About Us</li></NavLink>
              <NavLink to='/demos'><li className='p-2 hover:text-blue-500'>Demos</li></NavLink>              
              <NavLink to='/contact'><li className='p-2 hover:text-blue-500'>Contact Us</li></NavLink>
            </ul>
          </div>
            
        <div className="items-center justify-between hidden w-full md:flex md:w-auto md:order-1" id="navbar-sticky">
          <ul className="flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 font-medium border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:flex-row md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/" className="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Home</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/services" className="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Services</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/solutions" className="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Solutions</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/about" className="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">About Us</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/demos" className="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:border-gray-700">Demos</NavLink>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Navbar

I'm trying to make a responsive Navbar, when the mobile menu shows the whole Navbar is still clickable to toggle the menu, however can only close it using the x button. Trying to make the menu only open when the Hamburger menu button is clicked.
I tried adding a hidden button and blank divs, but the whole navbar is still able to toggle the menu.

I think you should to try this:
Wrap the hamburger icon in a button element and ensure the onClick handler is applied only to that button.
<div className="md:hidden z-10">
    <button
        onClick={handleClick} 
        className="focus:outline-none"
        aria-label={nav ? "Close Menu" : "Open Menu"}
    >
        {nav ? <FaTimes size={25} color='white' /> : <RxHamburgerMenu size={25} />}
    </button>
</div>

Other wise you can do Fine-Tuning the ul Menu:
useEffect(() => {
    const closeMenu = (e) => {
        if (!e.target.closest('nav') && nav) {
            setNav(false);
        }
    };
    document.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
}, [nav]);

With this approach, the menu will toggle only when the button is clicked, and accidental clicks on other parts of the navbar will no longer trigger it.

Thanks for poiting out the divs, I figured out the issue it was due to the 2nd button being displayed as well.  If i move the button into the correct div it works fine.
